# Hide comment in current buffer

Tags: elisp, comment, visibility

Is their a way to hide comment whatever the language used?

Like if I'm in cpp mode all `/* ... */` should be hide and if I'm on LaTeX mode, all `% ...` will be hide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package [hide-comnt](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hide-comnt.el) available from Melpa (now marmalade) can do it:

`M-x hide/show-comments-toggle`

Comment: it's a very handy package. thanks for that.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: hide-comnt doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Comment: @nroose see the edit.

Comment: There are a few packages out there that attempt this, but hide-comnt is the only one I see that actually makes comments appear to be removed rather than just blanking out the lines and leaving a bunch of unwanted whitespace.